# Windows phone manifest error when trying to change manifest

Tags: windows-phone-8, lockscreen

I have the following error when I try to modify the manifest file of my windows phone 8 app:

> Error 1  The 'ConsumerID' attribute is invalid - The value '{DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}' is invalid according to its datatype 'http:// WPCommontypes:ST_Guid' - The Pattern constraint failed.

Am just trying to change the lockscreen image from my app, so I just added this line under `<Tokens>` in the manifest:

```
<Extensions>
       <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreenImage" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default"/>
</Extensions>
```

Comment: You added what line in the manifest?

Comment: Give some code examples of what you changed. So is difficult to see where is the bug.

Comment: value of ConsumerID in error message is different from the one in manifest. Which one you actually have?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using LockScreen_Background as your ExtensionName or just LockScreen? You should be using LockScreen_Background.